# Recursive method with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to create a js object with a method which will print letter by letter with a 5 sec delay between each letter. But right now is not running. It writes it with no delay. Where is my error?

```js
class autoWrite{
    constructor(id,text){
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
    }
    startTyping(index=0){
        if(index==this.text.length){
            console.log("finish");
        }
        else{
            $("#"+this.id).append(this.text.charAt(index));
            setTimeout(this.startTyping(index+1),5000);
        }
    }
}
 a = new autoWrite("body-window","hello world");
 a.startTyping();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="body-window">

</div>
```

Comment: What about `setInterval`?

Comment: If you want to repeat a method, then use `.setInterval()`. This method has being created for this use case. Btw. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
setTimeout(this.startTyping(index+1),5000);
```

you're passing the result of `startTyping` as a function to be invoked with `setTimeout` - which is `undefined` - it is also invoked immediately with no delay. Try with:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  that.startTyping(index+1);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```js
 class autoWrite{
        constructor(id,text){
            this.id = id;
            this.text = text;
        }
        startTyping(index=0){
            if(index==this.text.length){
                console.log("finish");
            }
            else{
                $("#"+this.id).append(this.text.charAt(index));
                console.log(this.text.charAt(index))
                setTimeout(() => this.startTyping(index+1), 500);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    a = new autoWrite("body-window","hello world");
    a.startTyping();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="body-window">

</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) like this (better approach):

```js
 class autoWrite{
        constructor(id,text){
            this.id = id;
            this.text = text;
            this.index = 0;
        }
        startTyping(){
            if(this.index==this.text.length){
                console.log("finish");
                this.index += 1;
            } else {  $("#"+this.id).append(this.text.charAt(this.index));
                console.log(this.text.charAt(this.index));
                this.index += 1;
            }
        }
        start(){
           setInterval(() => {
             if(this.index <= this.text.length){
               this.startTyping();
             }
           }, 500);
          
        }
    }
    
    
    a = new autoWrite("body-window","hello world");
    a.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="body-window">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of setTimeout by MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), the first argument is the reference to the function you need to execute after the delay.

You can use the following code.

```js
class autoWrite{
    constructor(id,text){
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
    }
    startTyping(index=0){
        if(index==this.text.length){
            console.log("finish");
        }
        else{
            $("#"+this.id).append(this.text.charAt(index));
   let obj = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
    obj.startTyping(index+1);
            },5000);
        }
    }
}
 a = new autoWrite("body-window","hello world");
 a.startTyping();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="body-window">

</div>
```